# In tcpdf how can i know that $pdf->writeHTML will start from current or new page?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have html which I convert into pdf using `tcpdf` (PHP). First I use `$pdf->AddPage();` and then I use to write html in pdf i.e `$pdf->writeHTML()`. Here now suppose if I will again `$pdf->writeHTML` then how can I know that new `$pdf->writeHTML()` command will print from current page or new page? Because I have some content which I should show in current or next page as per pending space in current page. So if new `pdf->writeHTML()` will start from new page then I don't want to add manual page break in some content.

Comment: Is there any professional of tcpdf who can guide me regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCPDF will write content to the current page unless you manually add a page using [`TCPDF::AddPage()`](https://tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a5171e20b366b74523709d84c349c1ced) or `AutoPageBreak` is enabled and the content exceeds the set distance from the bottom of the page.

By default `AutoPageBreak` is enabled with a margin of 2cm. You can disable it (`$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false)`) or set a different margin (`$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin_in_user_measurement_units)`) using [`TCPDF::SetAutoPageBreak()`](https://tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a4430365ea0b9015b4aefedad1ba77ea9). The default measurement unit is millimetres.

Even if you have `AutoPageBreak` enabled, if you manually start a new page (`$pdf->AddPage()`) the new content will appear on this page until the bottom margin is exceeded again. Auto page break won't insert a second page break immediately after your manual break.

The content you add using [`TCPDF::WriteHTML()`](https://tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407) may be more than one page long. In this case `AutoPageBreak` will automatically add new pages as necessary. You can force content to always stay together on a page using CSS (`page-break-inside: avoid`). You can force a page break using `page-break-after: always`.

Comment: Is there any function of tcpdf which can be used to find current position in a page from where new print will be start ?

Comment: thanks matt. it resolved my problem. i liked  trick of page-break-inside: avoid

Comment: You can use `TCPDF::GetY()` to find our your current vertical position on the page in the user measurement unit.